# JavaFX TableView use checkboxes to populate list

Tags: java, checkbox, javafx, tableview

I'm fairly new to JavaFX and I'm trying to accomplish this principle in JavaFX: I've got a TableView populated with Student objects. I want the first column to be a checkbox with which I can select each row to perform a bulk action on the selected items (as commonly seen in for example mail applications).

I figured I shouldn't add a SimpleBooleanProperty to the Student class since it is only used in the view layer, which is why I thought I could implement it like this: when a checkbox is checked, the student gets added to a List selectedStudents; when it is unchecked, it is removed. Is this a good approach?

This is the code I've got so far (mainly based on copy-pasting from similar solutions):

```
    voornaamKolom.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("name"));
    familienaamKolom.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("fname"));
    promotorKolom.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>("comment"));

    selectedKolom.setCellValueFactory(
            new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Student, Boolean>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {

                @Override
                public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Student, Boolean> p) {
                    return new SimpleBooleanProperty(p.getValue() != null);
                }
            });

    selectedKolom.setCellFactory(
            new Callback<TableColumn<Student, Boolean>, TableCell<Student, Boolean>>() {

                @Override
                public TableCell<Student, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Student, Boolean> p) {
                    return new CheckBoxCell(studentenTabel);
                }

            });

    studentenTabel.getItems().setAll(getModel().getStudenten());
```

--

```
private class CheckBoxCell extends TableCell<Student, Boolean> {

    final CheckBox cellCheckBox = new CheckBox();

    CheckBoxCell(final TableView tblView) {

        cellCheckBox.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                int selectedIndex = getTableRow().getIndex();

                if (!cellCheckBox.isSelected()) {
                    getModel().selectStudent(selectedIndex); // add to selectedStudents
                } else {
                    getModel().deselectStudent(selectedIndex); // remove from selectedStudents
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //Display button if the row is not empty
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Boolean t, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(t, empty);
        if (!empty) {
            setGraphic(cellCheckBox);
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem with this code is that the checkboxes are not bound to the table rows. E.g. when I select the 2nd item and change the row order by sorting on another value, the 2nd item is still selected even though it represents another object. When new rows are added to the table, some of them get randomly selected too.

I know this code is probably quite dirty, like I said: I'm new to JavaFX. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The data type for your check box column seems to me it should be `Student`; i.e. it's a `TableColumn<Student, Student>`. The reason for this is that you're really presenting a view of the entire object itself: is the student contained in the collection of selected students. Sort of counter-intuitive but it makes it work.

See if this example helps. I don't have the nice separation of the data into a model that your code hints at, but you should be able to factor that in too.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableSet;
import javafx.collections.SetChangeListener;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class SelectableTable extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Item> itemTable = new TableView<>();
        for (int i=1; i<=40; i++) {
            itemTable.getItems().add(new Item("Item "+i));
        }
        TableColumn<Item, String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));


        TableColumn<Item, Item> selectedCol = new TableColumn<>("Select");

        // Collection of items currently selected via checkboxes in the table 
        // This will be passed to the TableCell implementation.
        ObservableSet<Item> selectedItems = FXCollections.observableSet();

        selectedCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Item,Item>, ObservableValue<Item>>() {

            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Item> call(CellDataFeatures<Item, Item> data) {
                return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(data.getValue());
            }
        });

        selectedCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Item, Item>, TableCell<Item, Item>>() {

            @Override
            public TableCell<Item, Item> call(
                    TableColumn<Item, Item> param) {
                return new CheckBoxCell(selectedItems);
            }
        });

        itemTable.getColumns().addAll(selectedCol, nameCol);

        Button displayButton = new Button("Display selected");
        displayButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                for (Item item : selectedItems) {
                    System.out.println(item.getName());
                }
            }
        });

        Button selectAllButton = new Button("Select all");
        selectAllButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                selectedItems.addAll(itemTable.getItems());
            }
        });

        Button selectNoneButton = new Button("Select none");
        selectNoneButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                selectedItems.clear();
            }
        });

        HBox buttons = new HBox(5);
        buttons.getChildren().addAll(selectAllButton, selectNoneButton, displayButton);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(itemTable);
        root.setBottom(buttons);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static class CheckBoxCell extends TableCell<Item, Item> {

        private final ObservableSet<Item> selectedItems ;
        private final CheckBox checkBox ;

        public CheckBoxCell(ObservableSet<Item> selectedItems) {
            this.selectedItems = selectedItems ;
            this.checkBox = new CheckBox() ;


            // listener to update the set of selected items when the 
            // check box is checked or unchecked:
            checkBox.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    if (checkBox.isSelected()) {
                        selectedItems.add(getItem());
                    } else {
                        selectedItems.remove(getItem());
                    }
                }
            });

            // listener to update the check box when the collection of selected
            // items changes:
            selectedItems.addListener(new SetChangeListener<Item>() {

                @Override
                public void onChanged(Change<? extends Item> change) {
                    Item item = getItem();
                    if (item != null) {
                        checkBox.setSelected(selectedItems.contains(item));
                    }
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(Item item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                checkBox.setSelected(selectedItems.contains(item));
                setGraphic(checkBox);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Item {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name ;
        }
        public final String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }
        public final void setName(String name) {
            this.name.set(name);
        }
        public Item(String name) {
            setName(name);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hero! Student, Student seems indeed counter-intuitive but it does the trick perfectly. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `getModel().selectStudent(selectedObject);`
and `getModel().deselectStudent(selectedObject);` instead. In here, `selectedObject` should be the object itself and not just the index. The model should point to the objects instead of indexes.

It's good to remember that you can make your model point to the exact objects you created. You just have to make sure the correct objects are being pointed to.

Comment: Sounds good, but selectedIndex is a variable I assigned to getTableRow().getIndex() in the line above, and there doesn't seem to exist a method getTableRow().getObject(). What can I use instead?

Comment: You can use `getTableRow().getItem()` to get the `Student` object from the current row. But see my (somewhat different) solution.

Comment: As James_D said, it's `getTableRow().getItem()`.

Comment: Although I used the other solution to fix my problem, this is still interesting to know! Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. You can use this as an alternative. :)